# javascript for checkbox checked

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sample of what I need: (click for full image)

[image: sample]

I want that when I click on any of the header checkbox, all the rows below that will be checked.

For example: when I click on *select all* checkbox of header then all the checkbox shown in grid must be checked and vice versa. Also when I click on any select row checkbox than that particular row must be selected.

Also I have child and parent node as admin has role wise menu and role details then clicking on cell[1][1] that is admin row first cell, then it should check or uncheck its child node too.

Answer (score 0):

From your badly worded question, i think this should help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".selectAll").bind("click", function() {
      var boxes = "input[name=" + $(this).attr("name") + "]";
       console.log(boxes);
      $.each($(boxes), function(i){
          $(this).prop("checked", $(".selectAll").prop("checked"));
      });
    });
});

   <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="" class="selectAll"/> SELECT ALL
   <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> I have a bike
   <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" /> I have a car
   <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Boat" /> I have a boat
   <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Jet" /> I have a jet
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ALmb3/

This relies on your creating your checkboxes correctly so they are group by their name.

Comment: sorry for the badly worded question.. and thanks for this but can i have javascript code for it..

Comment: The javascript is already there :). How about actually trying the code that Matthew so kindly have given you?